# How to make sure that my extension will be loaded after the another one?

Tags: vue.js, shopware

I have two plugins: my own Plugin1
and Plugin2 from the store.shopware.com

I am overriding some function in admin panel from the Plugin2 with Plugin1 and the override is not working every time, because of the order of loading of this extensions.

I added console.log's  onCreated and mostly the Plugin1's console log is showing first, but in 1/1000 cases the Plugin2 is loaded before than Plugin1 and override not work. I changed the installed_at properties of this plugins, but it didn't work.

Comment: I suggest that you need async await function to order in the way what you need

Comment: How do you include the plugins? can you share some code where we can see your pluginloading?

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to work with customEvents e.g. that are thrown from Plugin 1 and Plugin 2 is hearing on that? So you do not need an "hard" overwrite? You just pass the data you need to the event and Plugin 2 is doing the stuff it needs to do.

Comment: I am not sure if you understand my case so I try to explain it one again:

I would like to override method 'getList' of sw-product-list component in admin panel from Plugin2 with my Plugin1. It usually works but there is 1% chance to load Plugin1 before Plugin2 and there is the problem.

Comment: Maybe you should also have a look at this mixin: **src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/mixin/listing.mixin.js** - Line 301.

`'When using the listing mixin you have to implement your custom "getList()" method.`

Maybe you can extend / overwrite this mixin to call your plugin. Not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem and saw that there is a possibility to set a overrideIndex. We set it to a high value and it seems that this will always push your plugin to the end of the chain.

Please see:
https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/0d07dcc18bcdf9d7256e162f6f524d7570c8ade5/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/core/factory/async-component.factory.ts#L293

But i think this is a dirty way. I wonder how it is possible to get a global working solution to extend plugins for all developers.